# Accessing JSON sub attributes using Pandas from .csv file

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas

I have this nested JSON data set which I have converted to `.csv` using `pandas`:

```
[{
        "attribute1": "One",
        "attribute2": "Two",
        "attribute3": [{
            "attribute4": "Four",
            "attribute5": "Five"
        }, {
            "attribute4": "Four",
            "attribute5": "Five"
        }]
    }]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["attribute1", "attribute2", "attribute3"])
df.to_csv('example.csv')
```

The data in the column `attribute3` is still JSON. How can I access the values of subattributes of `attribute3` i.e `attribute4` and `attribute5` using indexing?
For instance something like this: `data[0][2:0]` for getting data at zeroth row, second column and its sub attribute zero.

I would appreciate some help regarding how to access nested values. Should I flatten the one single column that contains nested values? How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be easier to parse your original JSON (`data`) using [json_normalize()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html):

```
In [5]: pd.io.json.json_normalize(data, ['attribute3'], ['attribute1','attribute2'])
Out[5]:
  attribute4 attribute5 attribute1 attribute2
0       Four       Five        One        Two
1       Four       Five        One        Two
```